# Adding duplicated values to a BindingList

Tags: c#, addition, bindinglist

When I add information to a BindingList, it gets duplicated... I dont get how...

I have this class with the Lists:

```
public VideoRepository()
{
    videos = new BindingList<Video>();
    videosFiltered = new BindingList<Video>();
}

public BindingList<Video> videos { get; set; }
public BindingList<Video> videosFiltered { get; set; }

public void addVideo(Video video)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Size 1 " + videos.Count);
    videos.Add(video);
    videosFiltered.Add(video);
    Console.WriteLine("Size 2 " + videos.Count);
}
```

When I call the method `addVideo` the first print shows `Size 1 0` and the second print shows `Size 2 2`. Even when using the debuger...

What is the problem? Am I very drunk?

Comment: The first print is BEFORE the add, the second one is AFTER the Add

Comment: Yes I have, but I am wearing my glasses. My List is empty, so the first print should should print 0, as it is, then I add a object to my list videos, so I should have 1 object there, but it prints 2!

Comment: The print before should print 0, the list is empty, the second print shoul print 1, I only add one object to the list videos... but I get 2??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that both your `videos` and `videosFiltered` have public setters. The only way you can get the behavior described is if some external code (not shown here) sets them to one and the same `BindingList<Video>` instance.

You'd better remove the public setters.

Or, modify the code as follows

```
public void addVideo(Video video)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Size 1 " + videos.Count);
    videos.Add(video);
    if (videosFiltered != videos)
        videosFiltered.Add(video);
    Console.WriteLine("Size 2 " + videos.Count);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you were right, when I saw your code I noticed your if condition, and then I remembered another method, where I wanted to copy objects from one list to another, I used videosFiltered = videos, but left that uncommented... that was my problem. Thank for the help.